# Cannot execute binary file when using CMD command in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker

Im trying to build new image from an existing base image,
but I ran into weird behavior when I ran the new image.

my Dockerfile looks like this (I deleted all unnecessary code):

```
FROM base-image
CMD ls
```

Then I ran this new image, and got "cannot execute binary file" for the 'ls' script.

The weird part is that if I comment the CMD part i.e.:

```
FROM base-image
#CMD ls
```

the container runs perfectly and the ls command works manually (i.e. if I type "ls" inside the container, it works)

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Guess: `PATH` not properly set. Try `which ls` when logged into the container, then use `/usr/bin/ls` or whatever the result is in `CMD`.